# What is the smallest nonempty subset U of $R^2$ that is not a subspace of $R^2$ but is closed under addition and takes additive inverses?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vector-fields

This is a take on 1.C.7 of Axler's "Linear Algebra Done Right", but changed to "the smallest nonempty subset" instead of "an example of a nonempty subset".

When I was first doing this problem I thought of the subset ${(0,0),(1,1)}$ where $(1,1)+(1,1)=(0,0)$. This trick makes sense to me after reading the Digression on Fields section in Chapter 1. However, I am not sure how to prove that this subset is the smallest that satisfies the requirements or if my answer violates some rule of math.

The solutions manual gives $Z^2$ as the answer because it fails the scalar multiplication requirement but had consistent addition and additive inverses.

Comment: What about $\Bbb Z$ itself, meaning $\Bbb Z\times\{0\}$? As for your proposed example, if you look at vector spaces over the field with two elements, then your example is indeed closed under addition and additive inverses—but in that context, it's actually a (one-dimensional) subspace!

Comment: I don’t understand why the author assume that such a smallest subset exists? Going in the direction of Greg,  $2\mathbb Z \times \{0\}$ is even smaller (for the inclusion).

Comment: You should define what you mean by smallest.

Comment: $(1,1)+(1,1)=(2,2)\ne (0,0).$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no smallest: consider $ ... 2k \mathbb{Z} \times \{0\} \subsetneq ... \subsetneq 4 \mathbb{Z} \times \{0\} \subsetneq 2  \mathbb{Z} \times \{0\} \subsetneq  \mathbb{Z} \times \{0\}$. None of these sets is even *minimal*.

A smallest subset of $\mathbb{R}$  closed under addition and "minus" must be contained by every one of these sets, so it's contained by their intersection $S_0 = \{(0, 0)\}$. Since you're looking for *nonempty* suitably closed sets, the smallest has to equal $S_0$. However, that's a subspace.